# How to create dependent drop down lists containing unique distinct alphabetically sorted text values, with ignore Blanks?

Tags: list, excel, validation, excel-formula, vba

According to this picture there is `Table1`  in "Sheet1" containing initial data.

[image: sheet1: Data entered]

I need use `List` `Data validation` for 3 end columns of `Table2` in the `Sheet2`

i.e. Columns B, C, D in `Sheet2` should have data validation lists that are comprised of the unique sorted values of `Sheet1` columns A,B,C respectively. They should dynamically update as new items are added to `Sheet1`.

[image: Picture2 -destination data record table]

Note: I want prepare dependent data validation list, **without using helper sheet or helper column**.

In related same issues (questions & answers & articles e.g. [get-digital-help](https://www.get-digital-help.com/2009/05/25/create-a-drop-down-list-containing-only-unique-distinct-alphabetically-sorted-text-values-using-excel-array-formula/) and [microsoft](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2003-excel/excel-ignore-blanks-or-duplicate-in-data/189b81b7-95c8-4b1d-a77a-e5706a1820b6?auth=1) and [extendoffice](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2654-excel-dynamic-list-remove-blanks.html)), this below objects are not covered all together.

- dependent drop down lists with several (more than 2) columns.
- unique distinct alphabetically sorted text values
- ignore Blanks
- without using helper sheet or helper column

With formulas:

1) I tried for **ignoring blanks**:

```
 {=IFERROR(INDEX(Table1[order '# id], SMALL(IF(ISBLANK(Table1[order '# id]),"", ROW(Table1[order '# id])-MIN(ROW(Table1[order '# id]))+1), ROW(A2))),"")}
```

2) With **helper columns** i tried:

`{=INDEX(order,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($A$1:A1,Table1[order '# id]),0))} for unique value and {=INDEX(continent,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($C$1:C1,Table1[Continent])‌​+(order<>Sheet1!$E$2‌​)+(product<>Sheet1!$‌​E$5),0))}`

But I need to combine the 2 steps of remove blanks and unique values in one step and write in a Name if possible.

Comment: Are columns B, C, D in sheet2 supposed to have data validation lists that are comprised of the unique sorted values of sheet1 columns A,B,C respectively? And are they expected to dynamically update?  Have you tried anything? If so, what?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. .

Comment: Exactly I was read this references: [get-digital-help](https://www.get-digital-help.com/2009/05/25/create-a-drop-down-list-containing-only-unique-distinct-alphabetically-sorted-text-values-using-excel-array-formula/) and [microsoft](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2003-excel/excel-ignore-blanks-or-duplicate-in-data/189b81b7-95c8-4b1d-a77a-e5706a1820b6?auth=1) and [extendoffice](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2654-excel-dynamic-list-remove-blanks.html) and etc... but they didn't solve my issue.

Comment: Please move above from comments and edit your responses into your question. It makes it easier for people to find and can make the question more attractive to try and answer as it provides additional information. Including any error messages you get, and images of your desired result also help.

Comment: I removed that.

Comment: And add that information to the question.